# try-catch bypassing a step

Tags: function, powershell, try-catch

I have a script that tests connection to a list of servers, and if contactable, gets the status of a service, and puts the results into three variables, `$Computer`, `$Ping` (True/False), and `$Service` (Running or Stopped).

The output is in a hashtable but I can only get to show the servers that ARE contactable, and not the ones that cannot be contactable.

I have placed a `try`/`catch` in the `$Ping` block, as well as `-ErrorAction Stop`, so that it doesn't attempt to run the `$Service` script, and instead go to the next `$Computer` in the array. I think I am trying to do two things at once that are conflicting each other:

1. add the variables to the `@Splat` and
2. don't process any further.

There are actually many more remote registry queries in my script, which will be irrelevant if the `$Computer` cannot be contactable, but I have shortened it for this post.

```
Function Get-Ping {
    $Servers = (gc "c:\temp\test.txt")
    foreach ($Computer in $Servers) {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "---------------------------------" 
        Write-Host "QUERYING $Computer"
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "Performing ping test..."
        try {
            $Ping = Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Cannot Ping $Computer"
            Write-Host "Trying next computer..."
            Write-Host
            continue
        }
        if ($Ping) {$Ping="$True"}
        Write-Host $Computer "can be pinged"

        $svcRRStopped = $false
        if ($Computer -ne $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
            Write-Host "Check RemoteRegistry status..."
        }
        $svcRR = Get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -Include RemoteRegistry

        $SelectSplat = @{
            Property = (
                'Computer',
                'Ping',
                'Service'
        )}

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
              Computer=$Computer 
              Ping=$Ping
              Service=$svcRR.status
        } | Select-Object @SelectSplat
    }
}

$results = Get-Ping
$tableFragment = $results | Select 'Computer','Ping','Service' 
$tableFragment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.

```
function Get-Ping {
  Get-Content 'C:\temp\test.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $isAvailable = [bool](Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -EA SilentlyContinue)
    if ($isAvailable) {
      $rreg = Get-Service -Computer $_ -Name RemoteRegistry |
              Select-Object -Expand Status
    } else {
      $rreg = 'n/a'
    }
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Computer = $_ 
      Ping     = $isAvailable
      Service  = $rreg
    }
  }
}

Get-Ping
```

Comment: Thanks. It is, however, returning the last item in the text file 6 times (once for each item in the list),

Comment: Don't forget also, that there will be many more queries against each computer in the list, that should be ignored if PING is not available, but it SHOULD still add the value into the PSObject, rather than ignore it completely from the results

Comment: @JDGEEK I forgot to change the loop variable to `$_` when changing the loop from `foreach` to `ForEach-Object`. Fixed.

Comment: I now only get "Get-Service: Cannot find any service with the service name 'RemoteRegistry" for the first entry only

Comment: Does the remote host even allow remote connections from the computer where you're running that script? (i.e. can you manually run `Get-Service -Computer 'computername' -Name RemoteRegistry`?)

Comment: Yes I can. But I have gotten around this now. The whole idea was to get PS to skip the remainder of the script if it couldn't contact the machine, and continue off to the last step where it will add the results it has so far into a hash table. I'm used to VBS where I can use GOTO <name of function>

Comment: Function Get-ServerDetails
{
Foreach Computer
            {
            Do Step 1
                If Error, goto Step 10 of the function
            Do Step 2
                If Error, goto Step 10 of the function
            Do Step 3
            .
            .
            .
            .
            Do Step 10
                $Hash = @{blah!blah!blah!}
}
Execute Function and send results of $Hash via email

Comment: Do **not** use `GOTO`. Anywhere. Ever. The code I posted should produce objects where the `Service` property shows the status of the service if the computer is pingable, or `n/a` otherwise. Other properties can be filled the exact same way. If it doesn't work for you: please show your modified code and the actual results it produces (in your question).

Comment: I don't use GOTO - this was just a plain English explanation of what I wanted to do

Comment: Again: the code I posted should do what you're asking. If it doesn't: show the code you're currently using and the result it produces. In your question.

Comment: Hi, I have restarted a new PS session, and it seems to work now - I can work from here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the -Quiet Parameter:

```
Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet
```